# Extending a GraphQL Filter Definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, postgraphile

I have extended my graphql schema to add a totals resolver, but I can't seem to extend the filter to filter on this field. I can't figure out what can be wrong as it seems very simple, so maybe it's not supported? I am using Postgraphile with the makeExtendSchemaPlugin, but I believe the question is basic graphql syntax.

```
return {
  typeDefs: gql`
    extend type Note {
      lines: Int
    }
    extend type NoteFilter {
      lines: IntFilter
    }
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Note: {
      resolve: async(parent, args, ctx, info) => {
        // logic here
        return parent['@lines'].data.length;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems so simple. The count resolver works, and gives me how many lines are in the note, yet I am not able to filter on it. I don't want to put the filter logic in the lines property itself. If I define a new query and give it a NoteFilter, the filter exists but doesn't include my extended property (lines). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This is the end goal I would like for a query:

```
gql`
  {
    allNotes(filter: {
      lines: {
        greaterThan: 10
      }
    }) {
      id
      lines
      line {
        content   
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extending an input object type, the correct syntax is:

```
extend input NoteFilter {
  lines: IntFilter
}
```

In SDL, input object types are denoted as `input`, not `type`.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer to my question. If others find it, it is worth noting that while this puts the field in the filter, actually running a query with a filter on the field returns an "unable to resolve filter field" error. This makes sense as the field is calculated in my resolve method and will not be able to be used as a query parameter for limiting the actual executed query results